# Object is possibly 'null' (undefined)

Tags: angular, typescript

See, this is my code and it is saying few errors, which are: Object is possibly 'null', Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'. It is very irritating

```
  darkMode() {
    const text1 = document.querySelector("#text");
    text1.style.color = "white";

  }
```

Comment: Just put the condition and add last line in this condition if(text1){  text1.style.color = "white"; }

Comment: This should work: `const text1 = document.querySelector("#text") as HTMLElement`

Comment: But usually you don't want to use querySelector in Angular, there are better ways. If you show the HTML and how darkmode is called, I can help you set it up in a better way.

Comment: Sorry i can't give tick mark to anyone. But, it all worked.

Answer (score 4):

That is because there is no way TypeScript will know beforehand, that an element on the page will match the `#text` selector. Moreover, `document.querySelector()` returns `Element`, which the `style` property does not exist.

To fix the typing returned, you will need to manually typecast it to `HTMLElement`, i.e.:

```
const text1 = document.querySelector('#text') as HTMLElement;
```

---

Additional note: Casting it to `HTMLElement` also solve the null/undefined complaint, but this is only safe if you are yourself 100% sure the element will return an element. Otherwise, you need to do this:

```
const text1 = document.querySelector('#text') as HTMLElement | null;
if (text1) text1.style.color = 'white';
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put this condition and it's work fine for you.

```
darkMode() {
    const text1 = document.querySelector("#text");
    if(text1){
       text1.style.color = "white";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that are interested in one line. You do it like this

```
(document.querySelector('#text') as HTMLElement | null)?.style.color = 'white';
```